# Delete specific columns from csv file maintaining same structure on output

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I would like to delete column 3 and keep the same structure on output file.

input file

```
12,10,10,10 10,1
12,23 1,45,6,7
11  2,33,45,1,2
1,2,34,5,6
```

I tried

```
awk -F, '!($3="")' file | awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1'
12,10,10,10,1
12,23,1,6,7
11,2,33,1,2
1,2,5,6
```

Output desired

```
12,10,10 10,1
12,23 1,6,7
11  2,33,1,2
1,2,5,6
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: `cut -d "," -f 1-2,4- file`?

Comment: from the duplicate, `cut -d, --complement -f3` would also be a nice solution for this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use `sed` here:

```
sed -E 's/^(([^,]*,){2})[^,]*,/\1/' file

12,10,10 10,1
12,23 1,6,7
11  2,33,1,2
1,2,5,6
```

**Search regex:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start 1st capture group

  - `(`: Start 2nd capture group
  - `[^,]*,`: Match 0 or more non-comma characters followed by a comma
  - `){2}`: End 2nd capture group. `{2}` means match 2 pairs of above match
- `)`: End 1st capture group
- `[^,]*,`: Match 0 or more non-comma characters followed by a comma

**Replacement:**

- `\1`: Back-reference to captured group #1

Comment: anubhava, please can you explain how the code works ( the logic ), it can work  to able to delete any column ?. In my input example i show only 5 columns but this can be more? .. Appreciate your comments..

Comment: I have added detailed explanation in my answer. Let me know if there is any further doubt.

Comment: anuhava, works perfectly, many thanks for the explanation in the code

Answer (score 2):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's/^([^,]+,[^,]+,)[^,]+,/\1/' file
```

- `^` - start of the string
- `[^,]+` - match any char(s) except `,`
- `\1` - points to the 1st captured parenthesized group `(...)`

The output:

```
12,10,10 10,1
12,23 1,6,7
11  2,33,1,2
1,2,5,6
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(i=3;i<NF;i++)$i=$(i+1);NF--}1' file
12,10,10 10,1
12,23 1,6,7
11  2,33,1,2
1,2,5,6
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -l -aF/,/ -ne 'splice @F, 2, 1; print join ",", @F'
```

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`s
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the @F array
- `-F` specifies how to split (`/,/` means on comma)
- [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice) removes elements from arrays, in this case it removes 1 element at position 2.