# delete text with delimiter in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a text file in the below format . I need to remove the text between the first and second semicolon (delimiter ), but retain the second semicolon

```
$cat test.txt
abc;def;ghi;jkl
mno;pqr;stu,xxx
```

My expected output

```
abc;ghi;jkl
mno;stu,xxx
```

I tried using `sed 's/^([^;][^;]*);.*$/\1/'`, but it removes everything after the first semicolon. I also tried with `cut -d ';' -f2`, this only give the 2nd field as output.

Comment: typo error .  it's all semicolon.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  I tried using  sed 's/^\([^;][^;]*\);.*$/\1/'  , but it removes everthing after the first semicolon.  I also tried with  cut -d ';' -f2 , this only give the 2nd field as output.

Comment: Sure, please do add them in your question(comments are not meant for posting codes), thank you.

Comment: See: [Delete specific columns from csv file maintaining same structure on output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47813118/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cut`

```
cut -d";" -f2 --complement file
```

- `-d` is for *delimeter*, i.e ";" in your case
- `-f` is for *field*, i.e keep the fields listed
- `--complement` is to *reverse* the selection, i.e remove the fields listed

So:

```
$ cat test.txt
abc;def;ghi;jkl
mno;pqr;stu;xxx

$ cut -d";" -f2 --complement test.txt
abc;ghi;jkl 
mno;stu;xxx
```

Comment: You should mention that will only work with GNU `cut`, not a POSIX `cut`.

Comment: If the `--complement` option seems a bit unwieldy remember the option can be shortened to the first unambiguous possibility i.e `--comp` or even `--co`.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to fix OP's attempts here, with `sed` you could try following code. Simple explanation would be, create 1st back reference which has value till 1st occurrence of `;` then from 1st `;` to 2nd `;` don't keep it in backreference and keep rest of the value in 2nd back reference. Finally while substituting substitute it with 1st and 2nd back reference values.

```
sed -E 's/^([^;]*);[^;]*;(.*)/\1;\2/' Input_file
```

OR as per Ed's comment please try following;

```
sed -E 's/^([^;]*);[^;]*/\1/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it directly by simply removing the 2nd occurrence of the characters in question, e.g.

```
sed 's/[^;]*;//2' test.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed 's/[^;]*;//2' test.txt
abc;ghi;jkl
mno;stu,xxx
```

A thanks to [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)  for improvements here as well.

If you did want to use `awk`, you could simply replace the 2nd field with nothing as well, e.g.

```
awk -F';' '{sub(/;[^;]*/,"")}1' test.txt
```

(same output)

With a thanks to [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for the improvement to the original.

Or as Cyrus suggest with `cut`, deleting field 2, e.g.

```
cut -d';' -f-1,3- test.txt
```

(same output)

Comment: `cut -d';' -f2- test.txt` does not work as we expect for this question. It removes the first column, not the second. It essentially says "keep from column 2 and on".

Comment: I had one more hair-brained `awk` scheme. What about looping over all fields and just not outputting the 2nd? A little longer, but avoids all potential issues?

Comment: That'd be fine too. Or with GNU awk you could use `gensub()` just like you use `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed 's/;[^;]*//' file

abc;ghi;jkl
mno;stu,xxx
```

Comment: That's another creative way to get the 2nd occurrence `:)`

Answer (score 0):

super lazy awk solution

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2 'sub(/;[^;]+/,"")'
```

a more verbose solution but makes it clearer what it's doing

```
g/mawk 'BEGIN {FS=";+"; OFS=";"} ($2="")||($0=$0)&&($1=$1)'
```

clean out 2nd field, but since null string is assigned in, it returns 0 (false), thus requiring logical or `||` to continue.

`$0=$0` plus `$1=$1` to clean up extra `;`, which will also print it.